Whether there is a security problem in the explicit account&password through the private URL protocol
I want to pass account passwords to cmd via a custom URL protocol in Windows registry. Does this custom URL protocol pose security risks when transmitting account passwords?
custom URL protocol is defined in Windows registry and is used in browser.
If there are security concerns, how can I avoid risks?
